# How do I politely ask a convenor to not publish my name on the conference website?

Tags: etiquette, conference, presentation, website, privacy

I will be presenting a paper at a major conference in the Spring: this will be my academic debut!

The issue is that I have a permament teaching job (middle school) that does not permit time off to pursue academic pursuits: how ironic.  This conference entails an inter-continental trip and hence, three "sick days" off. Cough, cough.

My name is already up on the conference website for anyone to Google, i.e. my employer.

How do I politely ask the convenor of my session to hide my name or alter it in some form? Withrawal is not an option.

Comment: So you asked your boss, they told you no, and you plan to go anyway against their will by taking sick days?

Comment: As far as I can see, you are asking the conference organizer to lie for you.  I don't think it's fair to ask him/her for that.

Comment: How did you plan to get out of the fact that people will want to know who is presenting and you will want to take ownership of your presentation?

Comment: Take an unpaid leave instead of lying about sick days. It is not really you job's business what you do when you off job as long you're officially on leave.

Comment: "I have a permament teaching job (middle school) that does not permit time off to pursue academic pursuits: how ironic" Not really ironic. You're currently a middle school teacher - there's no research or academic pursuits here (like say, at a university)... so it's not unusual for them to not provide time off for such activities. Once you've achieved your PHD and work at a college/university, that sort of activity will be much more accepted as part of your job - not in addition to it.

Comment: So the kids can do it but the teachers can't? Bummer!

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov If unpaid leave is an option, it is clearly the right option. However, it may be difficult for a classroom teacher to get leave for a day on which they are scheduled to teach.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, well, what a surprise, to have a duty to work on job you've signed for! :) That's how we all work, it's not something specific to academia. I'd say it is not academia question - it's more for workplace.SE.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov: It's not a surprise at all, but in a job like a teacher's, it is also no surprise that the teacher cannot choose when to give their classes and when to skip them. Hence, taking a few days of so-called "unpaid leave" is a severe breach of contract rather than simply being "officially on leave".

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov Teachers have an expectation to be there and teach during session, period. Special leeway is given for specific and related things (such as a district-wide 9th Grade Math Teachers Workshop, or something), but isn't given for random things teachers want to do on personal time. Think about it, every time the teacher is gone, class is often reduced to watching videos or goofing off with a Sub. Essentially then, your student is being robbed education because the teacher wants to invest more time in a hobby not related to their professional work (teaching middle school in this case).

Comment: Teaching, or any other job that has to be done at very specific times and places, may not be the best choice to combine with PhD or similar studies. It would be better to try to find a job that has more flexibility.

Comment: @SnakeDoc Thanks to Alanis Morissette, there's an entire generation of people who don't know what the word "ironic" means. Literally none of them, if you catch my drift.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov. If I was not permitted an extra day to fly out for my PhD graduation, asking for three  days for a conference would not likely be granted. Now, getting a maternity leave is a whole different story...

Comment: @SnakeDoc Blood, sweat, and tears were invested in the completion of my PhD: docotoral research is not a "hobby". I teach interdisciplinary arts at the middle school level and my academic research is likewise interdisciplinary; hence, the latter is not unrelated. My expertise is applied to my curriculum every day - albeit it watered down to accomodate young young minds. It is so frustrating that teachers are reduced to consumers of research vs. producers.

Comment: @Insane: Exactly. This is why at least in North America, teaching is not as respected as other 'professional 'careers.

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan:  you are absolutely right: it may be time to emabark on a massive career change.  I put in twelve hours days to ensure that my classroom programming is top-notch. By 8:30 pm, my brain is too fried for an all-night orgy with Schopenhauer, Nietzsche, and Wagner...

Comment: @DistractedPhD it sounds like you should not teach middle school next term; instead try for a university or college. No matter how you slice it, your research activities are unlikely to be supported by a K-12 system. You'll have to do them on *your* time, or not do them at all. You may be able to slip by here with a sick day, but can you keep that up? And to what end? (and I do think you're underselling yourself if you have a PhD and are at a middle school. it sounds like your passion is your extra activities, pursue them!)

Comment: @DistractedPhD Hell by the time I was in middle school I was systematically scheduling when I would be 'sick' based off the number of allocated days!

Comment: FWIW. Taking sick leave, and not being sick is very often a legal overstepping. If you are covered by insurance, you will get money for being sick, while you're not. You should really use a form of vacation/leave suited for the situation. Recreational (if applicable, sometimes it's not, because you are not allowed to work, when you are supposed to rest in some jurisdictions.), unpaid, on-demand, depends on the actual law. Are you sure you are *not permitted* to go or just there is no special leave quota for such kind of activity?

Comment: **Please take extended discussion to [chat].**

Answer (score 43):

From both an ethical and a practical standpoint, ***you don't.*** The ethical reason should be obvious (and has been stated in comments); you are lying to your employer about leave, and asking the conference organisers to be complicit in this (presumably without their knowledge). If you want to take sick time when it's not permitted, that is your risk to take, don't ask others to shoulder that for you.

From a practical standpoint, you should really ask yourself if hiding your name in the conference proceedings is in your best interests (relative to the chances of your employer discovering via Google what you were up to). I will presume you are going to this conference to begin/advance/change to an academic career. Reputation is gold in academia, and by concealing your activity, ***you are actively hurting yourself and reducing the profile of your work.*** If you don't care about the profile of your work and your academic footprint, then why go to a conference? They are expensive, and there are much nicer things to do with your time on a transcontinental trip.

Comment: Just out of interest, how practical is it to appear under a pseudonym which is used for all academic purposes? (Much as a maiden name might continue to be used professionally after marriage)

Comment: I don't really have experience with that, but to me it seems very inconvenient. It's probably worth it in some cases (in situations of personal safety, name changes, etc), but it's probably going to raise many questions when people wonder why your academic name and your usual name are different. Absent common explanations (like a maiden name), it just seems like it's inviting gossip.

Comment: I have personally seen academics continue to use a name that they have formally changed away from (maiden name or other legal name change) in order to maintain their reputation they built up under their old name. I have never seen this be questioned, as it is perfectly logical to want all your publications to be easy to find by one name, so I don't think someone would have to give a reason.

Comment: @z_dood  : thank you for your thoughtful and considered response. I am caught in the middle of an ethical dilemma for certain but overlooked how my decision might  implicate the convenor.  I was going to ask for my first name to be reduced to an initial, Your term 'academic footprint' really resonated with me. At this stage of my early career, establishing my reputation is of first and foremost importance. My full name it is. Decision made.

Comment: Glad to hear it. As an academic, the thought of hitting a conference and having no one actually know I was there gave me a little shiver to terror :-)

Answer (score 16):

I am not going to lecture you on the ethicality of taking sick leave to go to a conference. Not that it sounds like a great idea to me, but let's focus on your actual question.

> How do I politely ask the convenor of my session to hide my name or alter it in some form? Withrawal is not an option.

What is the problem with just sending them an email, and saying that you "for personal reasons" don't want to show up as a presenter? It will seem slightly weird, but I can't really imagine them saying no to this, and "personal reasons" is generally accepted code for "I have my reasons, but I would rather not tell".

That being said, you should be aware that the Internet does not forget. If the web page is currently online with your name, there are definitely tools that will allow inquiring (and dedicated!) minds to later on find out that you actually *were* listed as a speaker at some point, even if they remove your name at some point.

Comment: not able to secure a leave to cover the three day conference and the conference is too important to withdraw from.  Beleive me, I would gladly welcome an unpaid leave.

Comment: GENUINE THANK YOU TO ALL FOR YOUR HONEST OPINIONS and REPRIMANDS : ) Just to clarify though, my intention was never to alter my name but to just hide it on the website or to reduce my first name to an initial. Lastly, I find my job far from "boring": I've dedicated almost a decade to teaching. With my PhD in hand now, it's a battle between the classroom and the ivory tower!